# Как git решает, в какую строну рисовать граф коммитов?

Tags: git

Допустим, был коммит в ветке branch1 и потом от него откололась ветка branch2 и в ней было сделано 2 коммита.
В branch1 тоже еще был сделан еще один коммит. И в конце был сделан merge ветки branch2 в branch1.

После этого ветки branch1 и branch2 были удалены и спустя годы разработки все коммиты оказались просто в master.

Теперь вопрос: как git выбирает, как именно нарисовать граф этих коммитов, что я описал выше?
У него на выбор 2 варианта:
[image: graph]

Как git выбирает, как именно изобразить граф? Как он понимает, что `commit 3` был созданием новой ветки, а не `commit 5`?

Дело в том, что я пишу программу, которая будет рисовать граф истории git. Я знаю, что есть готовые проги, но я это делаю в целях обучения.

Но я не хочу парсить вывод команды `git log --graph`. Я загружаю все данные о всех коммитах и на основе их рисую граф. Т.е. я знаю, какие у каждого коммита были коммиты-предки и коммиты-дети, но как узнать, какие именно коммиты-дети были именно созданием новых веток, а какие продолжением текущих веток?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коммите слияния (merge) все предки имеют порядок. Первый передок всегда из ветки в которую вливаются изменения, остальные в порядке перечисления в команде merge.

При построении графа предки выводятся слева направо. Соответственно ветка первого предка (чаще всего это master) получается левой и вертикальной.